# Jquery text(), syntax issue?

Tags: jquery, ajax, text

I have some strange comportement with my ajax request. The ajax request processes correctly, and the callback function removes a class `'invisible'`, that reveals a hidden div. In this div, I target an element with a "target" id. But quite strangely, when I want to add a text inside the div with an `$("#target").text('hello')`; most of my webpage disappears. A wrong syntax ? Any idea ?

Best,
Newben

Comment: What is contained in target by default?

Comment: it sounds that the **div** has been `closed` in a wrong way and wraps unwanted elements. try `#target {background-color: red}`

Comment: Provide a fiddle for best answers.

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try `$("#target").html('hello');`

Comment: @zerkms Darn jQuery always trips me up, too used to vanilla JS.

Comment: Right, in fact I had in my call back function an append method that wa called after the $("#target").text('hello'), so by switching it, it works now !! But since I am really not familiar to jquery, I have another issue : "target" is an id of a p tag that corresponds to a comment. So, if I want to have a unique comment text each time the user triggers the comment button, I must do an : var target = $('.target').last(); and then $(targetting).text(comment); but it doesn't work. Anybody has an idea ?

Comment: sorry i didn't precise that I changed target into a class to prevent uniqueness conflict :)

Comment: @Newben glad it helped. please upvote and/or accept the answer if it solved your problem. also, if you have other questions dont hesitate to create a new question :)